# Trouble with using "count" after using "having by" in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

SCHEMA:

films:

[id,title,release_year,country,duration,language,certification,gross,budget]

In how many different years were more than 200 movies released?

My query is

```
select count(release_year)
from films
group by release_year
having count(title)>200;
```

Expected outcome is 13.

Problem:
I am getting

```
Count
236
203
209
225
221
214
252
238
220
224
226
227
260
```

what am I missing here?

Comment: If you didn't notice, you're getting those 13 years as the result.

Comment: Having by isn't a thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a number, then you need a subquery:

```
select count(*)
from (select release_year
      from films
      group by release_year
      having count(title) > 200
     ) x;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can break it down by querying the years and counting the films released that year, then count the rows in that resultset:

```
with cte as (
    select release_year
    from   films
    having count(title) > 200
)
select count(*)
from cte;
```

or

```
select count(*)
from (
    select release_year
    from   films
    having count(title) > 200
) cte;
```

What you're doing is grouping by release year so you get one row per release year, and the number you get for each year is the number of rows where release_year is not null (`count(release_year)`)